# C++ *= not giving correct answer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to multiply all of the elements down the diagonal line. If for example, I want to find the sum I could use `+=` but whenever I try and use `*=` it returns a different answer to the correct. Here is my code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > U = 
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9},

};

double calculateDet(const std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix )
{
    double det = 0.0; 

    for(unsigned i = 0; (i < matrix.size()); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned j=0; (j < matrix[i].size()); j++)
        {
            if(i == j)
            {
                det *= matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return det; 
}
```

The calculation should be: `1*5*6 = 30` However, the answer I'm getting is 0.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have also tried to use the summation, so: `det += matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j]` but gives me a much higher value.

Comment: `det` initially is 0? Then `del *= whatever` will give you 0.

Comment: You start with 0. 0 Multiplied by anything is always 0. What did you expect?

Comment: And it should be `1*5*9=45` :)

Comment: `det += matrix[i][j] * matrix[i][j]` sums the squares of `matrix[i][j]`, so that result would be `1 * 1 + 5 * 5 + 9 * 9`.

Comment: The second loop is a bit pointless. You could just say `int j = i`. You're now doing pointless work to to find a value of j such that `i==j`, instead of just making it so.

Answer (score 10):

In your code you have

```
double det = 0.0; 
<...>
det *= matrix[i][j];
```

If you multiply anything by zero, you'll get zero. You should initialize `det` with `1` instead.

Comment: Also OP `The calculation should be: 1*5*6 = 30` are you sure it shouldnt be `1*5*9` ?

Comment: Init it with 1, or with the first value

Comment: @LPs Nope - http://ideone.com/GreeLu

Comment: Are u sure about the matrix passed to calculateDet func?

Comment: the answer 45 is correct. your algorithm does not calculate the determinant, its calculating the multiplication of diagonal. if(i == j) det *= ...

Comment: @LPs Yep - Sorted it now :) Thank you! Don't know why I got -3 but I should have realised, force of habit to initialise variables with 0 ........... Oooops